# Pandas Merge: The column label is not unique

Tags: pandas

Considering two tables: one which contains all the indices, and another which contains data for some indices. The purpose is to have an entry for all index, regardless of it having data, and if it does, then add it. Similar to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in SQL.
The indices table, named `dates`, could be something like:

```
     name week
0  name_0    0
1  name_0    1
2  name_0    2
3  name_0    3
4  name_0    4
5  name_0    5
6  name_1    0
7  name_1    1
8  name_1    2
```

so the table would contain 6 weeks for `name_0`, and 3 weeks for `name_1`.
Whereas the data table, named `data_holes`, could be:

```
     name week otherdata
0  name_0    1         2
1  name_0    2         5
2  name_0    5        20
3  name_1    1         5
```

The desired merge result would be:

```
name week other_data
0  name_0    0     N/A
1  name_0    1      2
2  name_0    2      5
3  name_0    3     N/A    
4  name_0    4     N/A
5  name_0    5      20
6  name_1    0     N/A
7  name_1    1     N/A
8  name_1    2      5
```

However, when using `dates.merge(data_holes, how='left', on=['name','week'])` I am faced with an error:

> ValueError: The column label 'week' is not unique.

Comment: Hi @anky_91, that is analogous to what I wrote, which yields the error.

Comment: I will consider this solved, as it was generated by a typo on my side. I am truly sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried both:

- `dates.merge(data_holes, how='left')` and
- `dates.merge(data_holes, how='left', on=['name','week'])`

and got the proper result.
Actually, `on=['name','week'])` is not needed, because *merge* by default
merges on all common columns.

Maybe you have some "too old" version of *Python* or *Pandas*?
I have:

- python: 3.7.0.final.0
- pandas: 0.24.2
- numpy: 1.16.3

If you have older versions, upgrade to the indicated above.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! However, as I pointed out, it was a typo on my side, that is why it was not working. Sorry for wasting your time. I will mark your reply as the answer so as to close the thread.

Answer (score 10):

I am aware that the question has already been answered but the last time the error about one of the columns mentioned `not being unique` on a `merge` operation came up I found out it was because in one of the dataframes to be merged it was duplicated.

For example in the following code:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=['col1','col2'])
```

If the error states that *col2 is not unique* perhaps  2 or more columns in either dataframe df1 or df2 have the name 'col2'.
The column values don't necessarily have to be completely the same for the error to be thrown just 2 or more columns having the same name on an 'on' parameter when the dataframe is about to undergo a merge.
If the answer above doesn't solve it, check this too.

Comment: Had the same exact problem; found the duplicated column, got rid of it and this fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Is it because of this ？:

```
dates.columns = [['name','week']]
```

double '[]'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30478507)